# WooCommerce - Mark all products as non-featured

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am novice to WordPress and WooCommerce. I am using `WordPress 5.0.2` with `WooCommerce 3.5.2`

In a project I have more than 21000 simple products and all are `featured`.

Now, I want to set them all as non-featured. I tried finding it using MySQL row query but I was not successful.

Then I found a we can get all featured products using:

```
$args = array(
    'featured' => true,
);
$products = wc_get_products( $args );
```

But I am not sure how to update them?

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `featured` is a term of the `product_visibility` taxonomy.

Marking a product `featured` adds a record to the `wp_term_relationships` table, thus linking the term and the product.

In your case, you could just remove these records with an SQL query.

```
DELETE tr 
FROM wp_term_relationships tr
LEFT JOIN wp_terms t
       ON t.term_id=tr.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE t.slug='featured'
```

**Backup your database before any attempt at mass modification!** 
I just checked the query with a simple test.